# JavaScript does not place data into a div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have some JS that takes some AJAX data from a PHP file from a database, loops through and places it in the HTML. It was working, and now it seems not too although the data is still coming from the PHP.

Javascript:

```
    function setDefault(){
    $("#downloads-div").empty();
    $.ajax({url: "action.php?action=fetch_downloads&category=%"}).done(function(data_raw){
      var data = JSON.parse(data_raw);
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        $("#downloads-div").append("<div class='col-md-4'><div class='thumbnail'><h4 class='list-group-item-heading'>" + data[i].title + "</h4><div align='right'><span style='display: inline-block; margin-right: 3px;' class='label label-default'>by " + data[i].author + "</span></div><a href='" + data[i].download_link + "'><img src='" + data[i].image + "' alt='" + data[i].title + "' class='img-thumbnail' align='center'></a><p>" + data[i].description + "</p><a href='" + data[i].download_link + "'><button type='button' class='btn btn-primary'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-download'></span> Download</button></a></div></div></div></div>");
      }
    });
  };
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="downloads-div">

</ul>
```

There is a load of other HTML and JS but that isn't called unless some buttons are pressed so doesn't really matter. I have no console errors and I am calling the function!

The page where the script is running is here: http://bluecode.org.uk/downloads.php

Thanks for your help!

Regards,

Comment: debug javascript. Does php return correctly the data?

Comment: `.downloads-div` is an `ul` not a div..

Comment: Yes it does; here for example: bluecode.org.uk/action.php?action=fetch_downloads&loco_type= @Mohamadshiralizadeh I have checked and it doesn't seem to matter what it is.

Comment: OP, @tomrac has already stated your error.

Comment: Rookie error! Ooops; thanks @tomrac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using class not id, so in your JS should be rather `$(".downloads-div")` than `$("#downloads-div")`

Comment: Thanks; feel really stupid for not seeing that!

Comment: I know...don't worry @alex

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(".downloads-div"`) because ul has `class="downloads-div"`

```
function setDefault(){
    $("#downloads-div").empty();
    $.ajax({url: "action.php?action=fetch_downloads&category=%"}).done(function(data_raw){
      var data = JSON.parse(data_raw);
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        $(".downloads-div").append("<div class='col-md-4'><div class='thumbnail'><h4 class='list-group-item-heading'>" + data[i].title + "</h4><div align='right'><span style='display: inline-block; margin-right: 3px;' class='label label-default'>by " + data[i].author + "</span></div><a href='" + data[i].download_link + "'><img src='" + data[i].image + "' alt='" + data[i].title + "' class='img-thumbnail' align='center'></a><p>" + data[i].description + "</p><a href='" + data[i].download_link + "'><button type='button' class='btn btn-primary'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-download'></span> Download</button></a></div></div></div></div>");
      }
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `downloads-div` has not `id` but `class`, so change your selectors in jQuery from `$("#downloads-div")` to `$(".downloads-div")`.

Answer (score 0):

You should reference the div using a class name since you are using

So your js would have to change like jQuery('.downloads-div')...